# SQL PHP - match records from one table to another based on several columns

Tags: php, sql, database

I have 2 tables:

tbl1:

```
+-------+-------+ 
| p_id  | f_id  |
+-------+-------+ 
| 1     | 2     | 
| 1     | 4     |   
| 2     | 1     |
| 3     | 4     |
| 4     | 1     | 
| 4     | 3     | 
+-------+-------+
```

tbl2:

```
+-------+-------+-------+ 
| u_id  | fname | lname | 
+-------+-------+-------+
| 1     | adam  | smith | 
| 2     | jon   | jones |
| 3     | sean  | dent  | 
| 4     | jack  | scott | 
+-------+-------+-------+
```

my logged in id (php) is:

```
$user->id // this returns '3'
```

I need to return each `u_id` in tbl2 for each `p_id` in tbl1 that does NOT have my `$user->id` (3 in this example) in it's corresponding `f_id`. For example, `4` should *not* be returned because it has a `3` in one of it's `f_id`'s. I hope this makes sense!!! Many thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query should work for you.

```
SELECT u_id FROM tbl2 
WHERE u_id NOT IN 
(SELECT p_id FROM tbl1 
where f_id = $user);
```

You will need to build the query in PHP so that it boils down to the above query in SQL.